# how can i choose the right database?

Tags: database

I am creating a website, using mostly html and some php pages, now I have to create a database and connect it with my website, for log in and requests, my question is what database should I go for, is Microsoft access good enough? or sql server or phpmyadmin? the website isn't large, it might get 6 requests per day, I am not a professional programmer but I know a few things about programming, please help

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is not database, have you compared prices for access/sql server/mysql?

Comment: no I haven't, I don't have a problem with prices, but which one would be useful for me..?

Comment: if you're new go with mysql simply because it seems to have a lot of documentation compared to other types, so it will be easier to find answers to your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an developer in Access.  Access technology is a Windows application, not intended for web applications.  It is not a back end database which is what a web server needs behind it.  The SQL Server - Express Edition (free) would be the product from the Microsoft family.  Of course there are other suitable shareware products out there, probably the best known being MySQL.

When the requirement is for internal needs, not public facing, but the users are geographically separated; then Access (and other Windows Applications) are platformed on a Remote Desktop Server (aka Terminal Services).

The other alternative to building your own web application is using one of the database centric web services: Soho, QuickBase, Knack, etc.